# Mutate factor to new variable in case_when() statement

Tags: r, case, r-factor

### Data Setup

I have a data set that appears somewhat like this simple dataframe below:

```
CAD_EXCHANGE <- 1.34
EUR_EXCHANGE <- 0.88
 
df <- tibble(
  shipment = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  invoice = c(rep(500, 5)),
  currency = factor(c("USD", "EUR", "CAD", NA, "SDD"))
)
 
df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  shipment invoice currency
  <chr>      <dbl> <fct>   
1 A            500 USD     
2 B            500 EUR     
3 C            500 CAD     
4 D            500 NA      
5 E            500 SDD     

levels(df$currency)
[1] "CAD" "EUR" "SDD" "USD"
```

### End Goal

I am trying to convert the invoices to USD for some common other currencies (EUR and CAD), but not all of them or if data is missing (i.e., SDD and `NA`).  My final data frame should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  shipment invoice currency invoice_converted currency_converted
  <chr>      <dbl> <fct>                <dbl> <fct>             
1 A            500 USD                    500 USD               
2 B            500 EUR                    568 USD               
3 C            500 CAD                    373 USD               
4 D            500 NA                     500 NA                
5 E            500 SDD                    500 SDD
```

### Trial 1 -- Does Not Work

In the future, I may have more than just these few currencies to convert, so I applied a `case_when()` statement.  This was my first attempt:

```
df_USD1 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    invoice_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ round(invoice / EUR_EXCHANGE),
      currency == "CAD" ~ round(invoice / CAD_EXCHANGE),
      TRUE ~ invoice
    ),
    currency_converted = case_when(currency == "EUR" ~ "USD",
                                   currency == "CAD" ~ "USD",
                                   TRUE ~ currency)
  )

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `currency_converted`.
i `currency_converted = case_when(...)`.
x must be a character vector, not a `factor` object.
```

With the above, I understand that I'm mixing character and factor in the assignment to `currency_converted` because I have the default `TRUE ~ currency` (and `currency` is a factor).  So I tried using only factors for the assignment...

### Trial 2 -- Works, but not in a reliable way

```
df_USD2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    invoice_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ round(invoice / EUR_EXCHANGE),
      currency == "CAD" ~ round(invoice / CAD_EXCHANGE),
      TRUE ~ invoice
    ),
    currency_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ currency[1],
      currency == "CAD" ~ currency[1],
      TRUE ~ currency)
  )
```

It works, but only because in my setup for this question, USD is in the first position, and I cannot rely on that.

```
> df$currency
[1] USD  EUR  CAD  <NA> SDD 
Levels: CAD EUR SDD USD
```

### Trial 3 -- Doesn't work

I thought I could try some other way of getting at the factor with subsetting, but this doesn't work:

```
df_USD3 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    invoice_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ round(invoice / EUR_EXCHANGE),
      currency == "CAD" ~ round(invoice / CAD_EXCHANGE),
      TRUE ~ invoice
    ),
    currency_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ df$currency[df$currency == "USD"],
      currency == "CAD" ~ df$currency[df$currency == "USD"],
      TRUE ~ currency
    )
  )

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `currency_converted`.
i `currency_converted = factor(...)`.
x `currency == "EUR" ~ df$currency[df$currency == "USD"]`, `currency == "CAD" ~ df$currency[df$currency == "USD"]` must be length 5 or one, not 2.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

And it seems to be that it's because of the `NA` that gets returned...

```
> df$currency[df$currency == "USD"]
[1] USD  <NA>
Levels: CAD EUR SDD USD
```

...because if I go back to my original `df` and replace that `NA` with some other currency, it would work -- but obviously I need to be able to keep `NA` where it belongs.

I feel like there's some very good way to do this, but I'm missing it despite reading up on factors and trying different things.  Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case_when` doesn't do the type conversion automatically - i.e. `currency` is `factor` whereas the returns from other conditions in `case_when` is just `character`.  So, we can force convert the `currency` to `character` to make all the returns same class and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    invoice_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ round(invoice / EUR_EXCHANGE),
      currency == "CAD" ~ round(invoice / CAD_EXCHANGE),
      TRUE ~ invoice
    ), currency_converted = case_when(currency == "EUR" ~ "USD",
                                   currency == "CAD" ~ "USD",
                                   TRUE ~ as.character(currency)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  shipment invoice currency invoice_converted currency_converted
  <chr>      <dbl> <fct>                <dbl> <chr>             
1 A            500 USD                    500 USD               
2 B            500 EUR                    568 USD               
3 C            500 CAD                    373 USD               
4 D            500 <NA>                   500 <NA>              
5 E            500 SDD                    500 SDD
```

---

If we want to keep it as a `factor`, either wrap with `factor` after the `case_when` or directly use `fct_recode` instead of `case_when`

```
library(forcats)
df %>%
  mutate(
    invoice_converted = case_when(
      currency == "EUR" ~ round(invoice / EUR_EXCHANGE),
      currency == "CAD" ~ round(invoice / CAD_EXCHANGE),
      TRUE ~ invoice
    ), currency_converted = fct_recode(currency, USD = "EUR", USD = "CAD"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  shipment invoice currency invoice_converted currency_converted
  <chr>      <dbl> <fct>                <dbl> <fct>             
1 A            500 USD                    500 USD               
2 B            500 EUR                    568 USD               
3 C            500 CAD                    373 USD               
4 D            500 <NA>                   500 <NA>              
5 E            500 SDD                    500 SDD
```